# How to get the path of a file in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

Lets says that I'm in a php class and I want the path to an image. I currenly use the relative path to my image from my class. If I move my class the path wont be valid anymore.

Is there a way to generate a path to the image like we do with assetic? Example: "@MyBundle/pathfromtherootofmybundle"

Answer (score 3):

According to symfony conventions, all of your images should be in your web/images (sub)folder(s). You can use symfony helpers such as image_tag to display those images in views, which will construct a proper URL for you based on this convention. You always have an ability to express a fixed route or a mixture using plain old PHP to point to a path on your file system.

Of course, another symfony convention is to only express public assets in the view, not in a PHP class file. Perhaps you need the image location as part of what the application does, and not necessarily for a view context.